# How to change name of twilio channel

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

The Twilio documentation page mentions using Roles to change the name of a channel (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/roles), but does not provide any example code. How would I do this in the below example:

```
var channel = this.state.channel;
var accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var authToken = 'your_auth_token';
var Twilio = require('twilio').Twilio;

var client = new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
var service = client.chat.services('ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

service.roles.list().then(function(response) {
 // what do I insert here to change the name of the channel variable
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In Twilio Programmable Chat each user gets a default role when they are created. There is also a default channel role that is assigned to each member that joins a channel. The roles say what permissions each user/member has. There is a [guide on roles and permissions available in the Chat documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/permissions) which I recommend you take a read through.

The default user role has these permissions:

- Create channel
- Get channel list (public, joined and invited)
- Join channel (public or invited to)
- Edit own user info

And the default channel member role has these permissions:

- Leave channel
- Get member list
- Get channel messages
- Add message
- Edit own message
- Edit own message attributes
- Remove own message

You can [update these roles or create new roles using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/roles). If you want users to be able to update the channel name you need to give them the `editChannelName` permission. You can either do this on the user level or the channel level. Once you have granted this permission to the role, or created a new role with this permission and assigned it to the user, the user will be able to call [`channel.updateFriendlyName`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.1.2/docs/Channel.html#updateFriendlyName__anchor) from the SDK.

Alternatively, you can use the [Channels resource in the REST API to change the friendly name of the channel too](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/channels?code-sample=code-update-a-channel&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x).

```
channel.update({
  friendlyName: 'channel_name',
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Hmm,I'm getting the error message "channel.update is not a function".....

Comment: Ok, you have `channel = this.state.channel;`. What is that? An actual `channel` object? Or a channel SID? Something else?

Comment: It's the actual channel object.

Comment: In the documentation, it shows that calling `update` on a channel object should work: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/channels?code-sample=code-update-a-channel&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x. It looks like you're using Twilio Node version 3, so that should work. It looks as though you are getting the channel object from a state though, has it been serialized down to just it's properties perhaps?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here. I was able to set callbacks using the same channel object. Weird.

Comment: It is weird, are you able to use `service.channels(channel.sid).update` for example?

Comment: I also tried adding a role giving title change access, but the updateFriendlyName is throwing a 'permission denied' error.

Comment: Have you given the user that role?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154244/discussion-between-alex-and-philnash).